# Getting Error "The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've published an ASP.NET Web API on IIS7 server. When I'm testing it locally. I get a framework error below:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the
>   `<compilation>` element of the Web.config file is used only to target
>   version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example,
>   '`<compilation targetFramework="4.0">`'). The 'targetFramework'
>   attribute currently references a version that is later than the
>   installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target
>   version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the
>   .NET Framework.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 20:   `</appSettings>`
>   Line 21:   `<system.web>`
>   Line 22:   `<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />`
>   Line 23:   `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`
>   Line 24:   `<authentication mode="None" />`

I'm not quite sure what it is wrong as I have an ASP.NET website running on the server using framework 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download .NET 4.5 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)
after successfully installation run command prompt(as administrator) and locate to this address:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

now run this command:

```
aspnet_regiis -iru
```

Answer (score 0):

> Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or **install the
>   required version of the .NET Framework**.

You need to install .NET 4.5 on the server where the website is running.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing .NET 4.5, you can change your application framework from `4.5` to `4.0` You can do this by right clicking on `project -> Properties -> Target Framework`.